# Passing Data from User Control in Master Page(s) to Content Page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls, master-pages

I've looked at several [similar](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/data-transfer-between-two-asp-net-pages/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640286/pass-data-into-user-control-on-master-page-from-sub-page) to this one and right now I am trying to use the FindControl method without success.

My Web Forms application has several master pages. Common to all master pages is a search box and button in a nav user control at the top. I'm trying to grab the search term entered on the SearchResults page:

```
HtmlGenericControl topNavDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("topNavDiv");
Control topNav = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("topNav");
if (topNav != null)
{
    TextBox searchBox = topNav.FindControl("searchBox") as TextBox;
    if (searchBox != null)
    {
        Response.Write(searchBox.Text.Trim());
    }
    else
    {
        resultsPanel.Visible = false;
        messagePanel.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

In the first line, the topNavDiv variable is null. I was considering accessing the user control via a master page property, but **with several different master pages I don't know how to determine the id of the master page as the search could be initiated from anywhere in the site...**

**UPDATE:**

I was able to grab the topNav div, searchBox textbox as follows:

```
Control topNav = (UserControl)Master.FindControl("topNav");
if (topNav != null)
{
    TextBox searchBox = topNav.FindControl("searchBox") as TextBox;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text))
    {
        Response.Write(searchBox.Text.Trim());
    }
    else
    {
        resultsPanel.Visible = false;
        messagePanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that the search box text entered is not being persisted.

Comment: do you visit this http://forums.asp.net/post/1516314.aspx

Comment: Not using nested master pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an Intranet site, I was able to utilize a query string parameter to obtain the search term as follows:

**Nav with Search Box User Control:**

```
<ul class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <li>
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" class="form-control col-lg-8" 
            placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;                  
        <asp:Button ID="searchButton" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="Search"
            runat="server" OnClick="searchButton_Click" />
    </li> 
</ul>
```

**User Control Code-Behind:**

```
protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Search/SearchResults.aspx?term="+searchBox.Text.Trim());
}
```

**Search Results Page Code-Behind:**

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["term"]))
    {
        term = Request.QueryString["term"].ToString();
        Response.Write(term);
    }
    else
    {
        resultsPanel.Visible = false;
        messagePanel.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

**What I would really like to know is if it is programmatically possible to determine in a page's code-behind, the identity of the master page of the requesting page?**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the data out of the query string for some reason you could use a Property on your MasterPage.cs file.

```
public string SearchTerm
{
    get
    {
        return searchBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Then you can use that wherever you need to like this:

```
MasterPage master = (MasterPage)this.Master;
master.SearchTerm;
```

Comment: this.Master would be the master page of the Search Results page - user can enter search term from any one of five master pages, so not sure if this will work...