# How to find label control from content page which is inside master page of user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, findcontrol

I have one page:**Abc.aspx**

On this **Abc.aspx** page i have used one master page that is **Master1.Master**.

Now on this master page i have rendered 1 usercontrol name as **Usercontrol1.ascx.**

On this User control i have put 1 label named as lbl1.

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1"></asp:Label>
```

So now on page load event of Abc.aspx page i want to find this control and i have tried but getting null:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lbl = ((Label)this.Master.FindControl("lbl1")); // null here
            ((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("lbl1")).Text = "Hello"; //error here:object reference not set to instance of object
        }
```

This is my master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master1.Master.cs" Inherits="" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
   <div id="Load">
                    <uc2:UserControl1 ID="UserControl1 " runat="server" />
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best approach is to provide a property in your `MasterPage` with a meaningful name and type `string`. This property gets/sets the text of the label in the `UserControl`. In order to meet this objective provide also  a property in your `UserControl` with the same meaningful name and type `string`. This property gets/sets the text of the label. You have to cast `this.Master` to the actual type of your `MasterPage` which is `Master1`. Then you can access this custom property.

Comment: Ok thank you sir.I have posted the answer.can you please review it and let me know if i am doing right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to provide a property in your `MasterPage` with a meaningful name and type `string`. This property gets/sets the text of the label in the `UserControl`.

In order to meet this objective provide also  a property in your `UserControl` with the same meaningful name and type `string`. This property gets/sets the text of the label.

You have to cast `this.Master` to the actual type of your `MasterPage` which is `Master1`. Then you can access this custom property.

So here is your `UserControl`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string MeaningfulNameForLabelText
    {
        get { return this.lbl1.Text; }
        set { this.lbl1.Text = value; }
    } 
}
```

This is your `MasterPage`

```
public partial class Master1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string MeaningfulNameForLabelText
    {
        get { return this.UserControl1.MeaningfulNameForLabelText; }
        set { this.UserControl1.MeaningfulNameForLabelText = value; }
    } 
}
```

and this is your page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var master = this.Master as Master1;
    if (master != null)
    {
        master.MeaningfulNameForLabelText = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to first find the parent container of the user control (e.g. #ParentContainer) and then use FindControl on this object to find the desired user control?

See: [Find a control on a page with a master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720590/find-a-control-on-a-page-with-a-master-page)

Like this:

```
UserControl control = this.Master.FindControl("ParentContainer").FindControl("lbl1") as UserControl;
```

Comment: What is ParentContainer??

Comment: Based on your updated answer I think this would be the ID of the UserControl, maybe you also need to add another FindControl for the div with ID 'Load' first.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some research i have found he answer:

First i have find that user control like below:

```
UserControl uch = Page.Master.FindControl("UserControl1 ") as UserControl;
```

After this i am finding my label from this user control like this:

```
if(uch!=null)
            {
                var data = (Label)uch.FindControl("lbl1");
                var d = data.Text; //getting text successfully
            }
```