# Casting objects from session in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, session-state

**Preamble**: I'm working in a legacy environment ASP.NET/.NET 2.0, *without* Visual Studio. Notepad++ and FTP at the moment. While hardly ideal, this is the hand I'm dealt at the moment. I have no direct/immediate control over the IIS instance, or the server machine at the moment.

---

I store an object, of type `Foo` in session:

```
this.Session["foo"] = new Foo();
this.Response.Redirect("the/second/page");
```

On the second page, I retrieve from session, and attempt to cast it for use:

```
Foo foo = (Foo) this.Session["foo"];
```

And I recieve:

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Foo' to type 'Foo'.`

When I compare the type names via `.GetType()` on the second page:

```
Foo in session:      ASP._dev_blah_aspx+Foo  
New instance of Foo: ASP._dev_blah_aspx+Foo
```

However their type GUIDs via `.GetType().GUID` are different:

```
Foo in session:      a67f218d-...
New instance of Foo: 267f20ea-...
```

---

Does this perhaps have anything to do with this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512064/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-x-to-type-x-asp-net)? I'd try, but refer to preamble.

Comment: Where does your class live? Is it in the App_Code folder, or defined on the page?

Comment: Defined on the page, script block; so nested class.

Comment: Is Foo marked as Serialized ?

Comment: @StefanP No, but I thought serialization only mattered for session objects persisting elsewhere. I'm just using the native session storage implementation. Not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload your code, try to force a recompile. Easiest way to do this is to *touch* you web.config. Just open it up with Notepad++ and add a space anywhere, so that the server recognizes that it has changed.

Comment: By golly, it worked... I have to touch `Web.config` every time I change the class definitions though. All the same, I'm marking this correct; T-3 minutes.

Comment: @Bracketworks - I'm glad it worked! I'm not sure if you need to do it every time. This error happens to me sporadically, and I assume it has to do with caching the DLLs in the server.

Comment: Thanks again @SystemDown, hopefully I won't have to do it *too* often. Better yet, hopefully I'll get the VS license and virtual server environment I'm waiting for ;)

Comment: @Bracketworks - Why not use the Express editions while you wait? They're free and quite adequate for what you need.

Comment: I would, but I'd rather just wait out my license for Premium instead of clogging the software request process.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can prevent this from happening is by always precompiling your site prior to uploading it (use the publish option from within visual studio)

Comment: Sorry @iamkrillin, "...ASP.NET/.NET 2.0, *without* Visual Studio."

Comment: Assuming you have a project file, you can still achieve the same thing by invoking msbuild directly from the command line.  (from within the directory with the project) 1)  msbuild /target:ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication /property:Configuration=Release;OutputPath=C:\Build\bin;WebProjectOuptutDir=C:\Build