# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.MyControlName_ascx' to type 'MyControlName'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website built by using asp.net.

In my local PC this working fine. But after I deploy this on server I got following error msg when I try to go to a page

```
--Data--System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal--Base Exception--System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.uc_eventmanagment_skill_skillbind_ascx' to type 'HRMS.uc.Skill.SkillBind'.
   at HRMS.Task.LoadAdminPanels(String page)
   at HRMS.Task.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)--Inner Exception--System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.uc_eventmanagment_skill_skillbind_ascx' to type 'HRMS.uc.Skill.SkillBind'.
   at HRMS.Task.LoadAdminPanels(String page)
   at HRMS.Task.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)--Source--System.Web--StackTrace--   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

TO Load the ASCX file I am using this code

```
            SkillBind SkillBind = (SkillBind)LoadControl("/uc/EventManagment/Skill/SkillBind.ascx");
            SkillBind.ID = "SkillBind";
            pHolderContainer.Controls.Add(SkillBind);
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Have you using `Page.LoadControl` to load `skillbind` ASCX control? Show more details including ASCX & ASPX page markups with code behind too.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Hi friend updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems originated from assignment of `ID` attribute before adding user control to the page:

```
SkillBind.ID = "SkillBind";
pHolderContainer.Controls.Add(SkillBind);
```

Back to the past times with webforms, I found that the user control should be added to `Control` inherited container before assigning any attribute to it, i.e. by swapping second and third line to make user control worked:

```
SkillBind SkillBind = (SkillBind)LoadControl("/uc/EventManagment/Skill/SkillBind.ascx");
pHolderContainer.Controls.Add(SkillBind); // assign user control first
SkillBind.ID = "SkillBind"; // then setting ID attribute
```

Also, don't forget to include this reference directive line on ASPX page(s) holding `SkillBind` control:

```
<%@ Reference Control="/uc/EventManagment/Skill/SkillBind.ascx" %>
```

Then add this element in development version of web.config to flush out such errors (optional):

```
<compilation batch="false"/>
```

Afterwards, try cleaning up & rebuild the project.

Related issues:

[Unable to cast object of type 'X' to type 'X' - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512064/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-x-to-type-x-asp-net)

[Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.MyControlName_ascx' to type 'MyControlName'.](https://forums.asp.net/t/903462.aspx?Unable%20to%20cast%20object%20of%20type%20ASP%20MyControlName_ascx%20to%20type%20MyControlName%20)